# XCache loses performance gain after a day or so

Tags: php5

I'm having some performance problems with XCache and PHP5 running on a Ubuntu 8.04 server. A few Zend Framework applications peak at about 12MB of memory. General response time before Apache 2 can serve the page is around 550ms to 950ms. When I turn on XCache, restart Apache 2 and refresh the page the first time the results are the same. The second time however gives a increase of about 50%. Pages get served faster and peak memory is around 2MB to 4MB.

However, after a day of usage there's no more gain in using XCache. Peak memory usage and response time drop back to their old values.

I've tried increasing `xcache.size` to `64M` (initially it was set to `16M`). This helped, but only for a couple of hours. I've also set `xcache.count` to `4` as the server has a quad-core processor. However, this didn't seem to do it either so I changed the defaults of `xcache.ttl` to `3600` and `xcache.gc_interval` to 900. Hoping that old cache entries would expire. Still, no difference. When I manually invoke `/etc/init.d/apache2 reload` the cache seems to get reset and all is well again, for only a day or so.

The server is hosting a bunch of lighter PHP based websites and a couple of Zend Framework based ones. The latter really benefit from the performance increase by XCache.

Any ideas what to try next?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eventually it was a memory issue. I've increased the `size` to `194M` and also made the `gc_interval` shorter, as well as the `ttl`.

We're hosting several PHP based websites (around 100 I think). Most of them are very light, but some use Zend Framework and different versions of them. The server has enough memory to spare so increasing the cache size and fiddling with the `ttl` and `gc_interval` made things a lot better.

Another tip, set up the XCache Administration page. Gives you a nice overview of what's being cached.